# Why is the "Zeor Error" Line in my Matlab Neural Network Histogram skewed?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, histogram

I am running an Artificial Neural Network algorithm in Matlab using the following [code that is found here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_analyse_the_performance_of_ANN_for_classification_in_MATLAB_graph_attached):

```
train_target = zeros(40,200);
for row = 1 : size(train_target, 1)
    col = 5*(row-1)+1;
    train_target(row, col:col+4) = 1;
end

%%%%%%%% Creating Network and Training Them %%%%%%%%%%%
rand('seed', 491218382)
net = patternnet([90]);
net.divideFcn = 'divideint';
net.divideParam.trainRatio =100/100;%% only training
net.divideParam.valRatio = 00/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 00/100;
net.trainParam.goal=1e-25;
for i=2:2%%% set the activation function linear for the output layer
    net.layers{i}.transferFcn = 'purelin';
end

% Train network
[net,tr] = trainrp(net,train_images,train_target);
```

My success rate is stuck to around 20% at best case.  I also found that the Error Histogram is skewed like this:

[image]

Can you tell me what might be the issue that is causing the poor success rate?

As a background:

1. I have 40 subjects, with 5 images per subjects (= total of 200 Training images)
2. I used PCA to extract the features from the images.
3. I then ran the code using the test images that was projected as per the PCA algorithm.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Never heard about a "Zeor Error".

Comment: Did you find the problem? I have the same issue with Matlab 2016a